# Sumit button value cannot be fetched

Tags: jsp, liferay, jsp-tags, liferay-aui

I have a `aui-form` with a two submit buttons. For each button I have a `if` condition. I tried getting the button value  but its returning `null`(checked in debug mode). Can anyone explain me why is this happening and what's the solution?

Comment: Would you rather like to show you code? So that anyone may help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

(This is all just educated guessing as you didn't provide much information - see the comment of  Parkash Kumar)

If you have placed your submit button in an if tag (taglib), the button might not be there due to the if statement, hence returning null when you try to access it via JavaScript.